# my activity work fine on 4.0 not work on 4.2

Tags: android

My activity does not work on Android 4.1, but it works fine on 2.2, 2.3, and 4.0. Some error show in the logcat I pasted below.

What is happening?

```
public class fifthscreen extends Activity {
    String num = null;
    TextView ingredient;
    ImageButton slideHandleButton;

    String name;
    String name2;
    long Menu_ID;
    String dish_name;
    String Type;
    String status;
    String message;
    // HorizontalListView listview;
    // CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
    String DescriptionAPI;
    // ImageLoader2 imgLoader;
    TextView txt1, txt2, txt3;
    ImageView img1;
    String URL, URL2;
    String SelectMenuAPI;
    static ArrayList < Long > Category_ID = new ArrayList < Long > ();
    static ArrayList < String > Category_name = new ArrayList < String > ();
    static ArrayList < String > Category_image = new ArrayList < String > ();
    public static String allergen2;

    // private AQuery androidAQuery;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);
    ingredient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ingredient);
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_button_image);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuname);
    // txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_button_text1);
    txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

    Intent iGet = getIntent();

    ImageView options = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.options5);
    // androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);

     options.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent iMenuList = new Intent(fifthscreen.this, LinkButtons.class); startActivity(iMenuList);}});

    dish_name = iGet.getStringExtra("dish_name");

    ImageView btnback = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnback);

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                   @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                   finish();}
                   });

    parseJSONData();

    }

    void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();

    }

    public void parseJSONData() {

    SelectMenuAPI = Utils.dishdescription + dish_name;

    // SelectMenuAPI = Utils.dishdescription;

    clearData();
    URL = SelectMenuAPI;
    URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

    // URL2 = SelectMenuAPI;

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL2);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        str += line;
        }

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

        JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
        String[]mVal = new String[school2.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {

            String name = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
            txt1.setText(name);

            String description = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");

            txt3.setText(description);

            String url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");

            androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, false, false);

        }

        JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");

        final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);

        for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {

            String s = String.valueOf(j + 1);

            final View row = createRow(school3.getJSONObject(s));
            table.addView(row);

        }

        JSONArray school4 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_allergen");
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < school4.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = school4.getJSONObject(i);

            Category_ID.add((long) i);
            Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
            Category_image.add(object.getString("image"));
            listview.setAdapter(cla);

        }

        final LinearLayout table3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table3);

        JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

        for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = school5.getJSONObject(i);

            final View row2 = createRow2(school5.getJSONObject(i));
            table3.addView(row2);

        }

        }

        else {

        JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);

            Category_ID.add((long) i);
            Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));

        }

        }

    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public View createRow(JSONObject item) throws JSONException {
    View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
     ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.localTime)).setText(item.getString("qty"));
     ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp)).setText(item.getString("name"));

     return row;
    } public View createRow2(JSONObject item) throws JSONException {

    View row2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
     ((TextView) row2.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(item.getString("name"));
     ((TextView) row2.findViewById(R.id.subingredients)).setText(item.getString("sub_ingredients"));

     return row2;
}}
```

Logcat:

```
 Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
  Shutting down VM
  threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
 ComponentInfo{com.schoollunchapp/com.schoollunchapp.fifthscreen}: 
  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection
      (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at  
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at  
    org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.schoollunchapp.fifthscreen.parseJSONData(fifthscreen.java:196)
at com.schoollunchapp.fifthscreen.onCreate(fifthscreen.java:157)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of absence of `AsyncTask`.  Put all `HttpClient` logic to `AsyncTask`.

From your logs:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You can't run `parseJSONData` on main Thread.

Here is some example how to implement it:

```
 private class AsyncRequestConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private final Request request;

    public AsyncRequestConnection(Request request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HttpPost p = createRequestHttpMessage(request);
            String resp = new String(stripResponse(getRequestClient().execute(p)));
            Log.v(TAG, resp);
            return resp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot complete API request", e);
            cancel(false);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        request.backoff();
        if (request.hasReachedMaxBackoff()) {
            request.cancel(R.string.error_internal);
        } else {
            requestQueue.enqueue(request);              
        }
        requestConnection = null;
        nextRequest();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            request.attachResponse(result);
            request.handleResponse();               
            requestConnection = null;
            nextRequest();
        } else {
            request.cancel(R.string.error_internal);
        }
    }
}
```

From your Activity just call it:

```
 AsyncRequestConnection task = new AsyncRequestConnection ();
 task.execute();
```

Comment: I posted example, read it and adapt your code to that example.

Comment: which method is used   public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{   or  AsyncRequestConnection task = new AsyncRequestConnection ();

Comment: `AsyncRequestConnection task = new AsyncRequestConnection ();
 task.execute(); `

Comment: butin ur example Async is seprate class how do i update my ui from there? how to call Asyntask inside my mainActvity

Comment: make class private and put in into your activity

Comment: how? im confuse im showtextview inside parse method    txt1.setText(name);  how do i show textview form other classs AsyncRequestConnection

Comment: Sorry but I cant describe you how all this stuff works, you can read it 1st, I answered on your question why it doesnt work and pointed what to do. If you feel that my answer helped you please sign V and up vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All network related operations are not to be run in the UI thread. This must be causing the issue. For more details.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html